# File comparison in two directories

Tags: python-3.x, loops, comparison

I am comparing all files in two directories, if comparison is greater than 90% so i continue the outer loop and i want to remove the file in the second directory that was matched so that the second file in the first directory doesn't compare with the file that's already matched.

Here's what i've tried:

```
for i for i in sorted_files:
    for j in sorted_github_files:
            #pdb.set_trace()
            with open(f'./files/{i}') as f1:
                try:
                    text1 = f1.read()
                except:
                    pass
            with open(f'./github_files/{j}') as f2:
                try:
                    text2 = f2.read()
                except:
                    pass
            m = SequenceMatcher(None, text1, text2)
            print("file1:", i, "file2:", j)
            if m.ratio() > 0.90:
                 os.remove(f'./github_files/{j}')
                 break
```

I know i cannot change the iteration once it's in action that's why its returning me file not found error i dont want to use try except blocks. Any ideas appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to point out:

- Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Your first for loop is not working since you used `for i for i ..``
- If you want to iterate over the files in list1 (sorted_files) first, then read the file outside of the second loop
- I would add the files that match with a ratio over 0.90 to a new list and remove the files afterward so your items do not change during the iteration
- You can find the test-data i created and used [here](https://file.io/2213CXddG8BX)

```
import os
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# define your two folders, full paths
first_path = os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\testfolder\a")
second_path = os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\testfolder\b")

# get files from folder
first_path_files = os.listdir(first_path)
second_path_files = os.listdir(second_path)

# join path and filenames
first_folder = [os.path.join(first_path, f) for f in first_path_files]
second_folder = [os.path.join(second_path, f) for f in second_path_files]

# empty list for matching results
matched_files = []

# iterate over the files in the first folder
for file_one in first_folder:
    # read file content
    with open(file_one, "r") as f:
        file_one_text = f.read()

    # iterate over the files in the second folder
    for file_two in second_folder:
        # read file content
        with open(file_two, "r") as f:
            file_two_text = f.read()

        # match the two file contents
        match = SequenceMatcher(None, file_one_text, file_two_text)
        if match.ratio() > 0.90:
            print(f"Match found ({match.ratio()}): '{file_one}' | '{file_two}'")
            # TODO: here you have to decide if you rather want to remove files from the first or second folder
            matched_files.append(file_two)  # i delete files from the second folder

# remove duplicates from the resulted list
matched_files = list(set(matched_files))

# remove the files
for f in matched_files:
    print(f"Removing file: {f}")
    os.remove(f)
```